# How to use function argument as a key in object interface

Tags: typescript

I have a function that manipulates an array of unknown objects in which I have a `nested_key` as parameter. When I'm trying to use it for accessing a key in the object, typescript of course complains because it doesn't know the key is present in the object. Is there any way to define an interface that would take that parameter and add it into the typescript interface as key?

Simplified function:

```
interface NestedItem {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

function manipulate(arr: NestedItem[], nested_key: string) {
  console.log(arr[0][nested_key].length)
}
```

So what I need exactly is to somehow use the value of `nested_key` like e.g. this:

```
interface NestedItem {
  [key: nested_value]: unknown[]
}
```

I also tried to first check whether the prop is the correct type but that seems not to help when checking with this function:

`const is_array = (value: unknown): value is unknown[] => Array.isArray(value)`

Comment: seems working fine to me https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQM6QCYElIC2yA3gFDLIDaA1hAJ4BcyWUoA5gLpMCuI1IAewDuIUgF9SpGLwRhgAkMgJwQwAA7cANnEgAKOFChN0WCHkKUOAGmQhMOAPq1GzMKxBsAlCXLIDUSgAGDko7U2wneg5kAF5kAHIwAAtgDGRkqGE06EyoePEgA

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the example... I have updated it to actually make it throw and explain more what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

instead of `unknown` use `any` so your interface should be

```
interface NestedItem {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

and use safe navigation operator `?` while fetching the length so it doesn't break your code in case the key is not in the arr

```
function manipulate(arr: NestedItem[], nested_key: string) {
  console.log(arr[0][nested_key]?.length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible extension to your function could be, ensuring that `nested_key` is a key of `NestedItem`, using the `keyof` keyword.

```js
interface NestedItem {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

function manipulate(arr: NestedItem[], nested_key: keyof NestedItem) {
  arr[0][nested_key] = 'new value'
}
```

Additionally, [immutability](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-immutability-in-javascript/) is important to consider.

If your Array (`arr`) cannot be mutated, it may be wise to spread `arr` first to a temporary object, like so:

```js
function manipulate(arr: NestedItem[], nested_key: keyof NestedItem):NestedItem[] {
  let resultObject = [...arr];
  resultObject[0][nested_key] = 'new value';
  return resultObject;
}
```

OR:

```js
function manipulate(arr: NestedItem[], nested_key: keyof NestedItem):NestedItem[] {
  let resultObject = [...arr];
  resultObject[0] = {
    ...resultObject[0],
    [nested_key]: 'new value'
  };
  return resultObject;
}
```

NB: I am a fan of [produce](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/produce/) by Immer which can help handle the whole idea of immutability